# Memory Issues in developing Android App

Tags: eclipse

I am presently trying to develop an Image Processing based app for android mobiles using Eclipse. My app consists of several buttons and sub-menu buttons as well. I am trying to make it universal(so that it can run on any resolutions) using switch case for the different resolutions, and thereby different resources for different resolutions. The problem is, I am encountering memory overload problems. It runs fine on Xperia U, but not on Galaxy S, and also crashes in the Emulator. I haven't used XMl for my app, and have designed the entire UI programmatically. Please advice me on how to solve this problem. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question sis very general but here are some points that might help:

1. Designing everything programmatically means your app will be slow and will create everything on runtime. It is not using the design optimization of Android UI by not using XML.
2. What context are you using in order to create UI objects. If you are tying the UI objects to the apps context rather than activities' context, all the components of UI will remain in memory unless the app is killed. Unlike in activity as soon as the activity is destroyed all its UI components are killed.
3. You could use XMl inflator in order to reduce work in Java, by reusing components created in XML . This will help you optimize some sub components that you are using repetitively.